# Is it safe/acceptable to call SDL_SetTextureColorMod every frame multiple times?

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

As a simple way to render multiple textures that are the same other than color I load a plain white circle in to an `SDL_Texture` then just call `SDL_SetTextureColorMod()` giving it the color I want to make the circle.

This all works fine if the textures are individual (Example 1) but if I am sharing the `SDL_Texture` so that mutiple objects all reference it, it means that `SDL_SetTextureColorMod()` must be called every render frame before the object renders the texture since the color it gave last time may have been changed by another object (Example 2).

Is calling `SDL_SetTextureColorMod()` every render frame, for potentially quite a lot of objects sharing a texture, going to cause major performance issues?

The reason it is required is the system is designed using a shared texture functionality with basic reference counting (I understand that there are probably better ways to do this using smart pointers but that is not the topic for discussion here). Is it going to be better to just let each object have it's own copy of the `SDL_Texture` so it only has to set the color once (or whenever it needs to change) rather than every render frame?

Example 1:

```
SDL_Texture* tex1;
SDL_Texture* tex2;
SDL_Texture* tex3;
...
// All 3 instances have their own SDL_Texture
MyObject A(tex1);
MyObject B(tex2);
MyObject C(tex3);
...
// A call to set the color of the texture is only required once for each class
```

Example 2:

```
SDL_Texture* tex;
...
// All 3 instances share the SDL_Texture
MyObject A(tex);
MyObject B(tex);
MyObject C(tex);
...
// A call to set the color of the texture must be made before rendering 
// each object to ensure that any other object has not set a different color.
// E.g if the draw order was A, B, C and the color was set to be different
// for each object then before rendering B, each frame it would need to set 
// the color again otherwise it would have the color of A and the same 
// for the others
```

Edit: This would also extend to `SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod()` and `SDL_SetTextureBlendMode()` or other similar functions

For reference I'm using SDL2.

Update: Originally it was thought that the call to the function is only updating a color blending flag. I have done some more investigation and this is partially correct which can be seen in the function in - http://pastebin.com/pMjgVkmM

However, if the renderer has a function assigned for `SetTextureColorMod()` which appears to be the case in most parts, then it mapped to a function 'SW_SetTextureColorMod()' - http://pastebin.com/qYtxD0TH

This in turn calls `SDL_SetSurfaceColorMod()` - http://pastebin.com/GrsVibAz

My concern here is at this point there is a potential call of `SDL_InvalidateMap` which I think can cause deallocation although I am not sure - http://pastebin.com/r0HGJYHT

Comment: I would recommend adding the C or C++ tag to this post to enable syntax highlighting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SDL_SetTextureColorMod` doesn't update texture texels - it saves multiplier colour and raises SDL_MODTEXTURE_COLOR flag. Subsequent RenderCopy on that texture will multiply texels with fixed colour.

Since it don't modify texture, and just a little constant within texture header, it is completely ok to set it many times in render frame for the same texture. Cloning textures would be counterproductive (a lot more memory usage, and potentially lower framerate due to higher memory bandwidth pressure).

Comment: This would appear to be the case but I have been doing some more research and found that it alter the state of 
the SDL_COPY_MODULATE_COLOR flag as you say, but in turn might cause a texture reallocation (if I understand the meaning of SDL_InvalidateMap() right) This is because it just forwards the call to some renderer defined function. I think most if not all renderers seem to use the implementation from SW_SetTextureColorMod which redirects to SDL_SetSurfaceColorMod

Comment: With software implementation, it invalidates blitting cache, which may lead to cache recreation. It doesn't happen with any hardware accelerated implementation because they don't have any cache (nor they need one).

Comment: I have accepted this as the answer but I think there is quite a bit more to the background workings as discussed in the SDL forum post I made - https://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=10555&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0

Comment: If you don't believe me, you can always compile SDL with debugging symbols, set breakpoint in interested function and step into it. For most HW implementations (except directfb) this function isn't defined - so it can't do what you've written, only sets colour marking and flag.

Comment: Yeah I went ahead and did some following of the code just to get it clear in my own head what was happening and I'm comfortable with the fact that all that happens is indeed the colour is changed and the flag set to tell the renderer to use it. Many thanks.