# SDL Clearing SDL_SetTextureColorMod effect

Tags: sdl

I am using SDL_SetTextureColorMod function to modify a texture. 
As seen [In this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969783/is-it-safe-acceptable-to-call-sdl-settexturecolormod-every-frame-multiple-times), The function does not modify the texture itself, only does the color modification when drawing.

The problem is, that upon calling SDL_SetTextureColorMod , I am unable to reset the effect, and I did not find anything online. 
So in short, I want to add for example darken effect to texture. But then, I want to be able to draw the original texture.
When pressing G in the application, effect is applied.
I also tried

```
SDL_SetTextureColorMod(texture, 1, 1, 1);
```

but that did not reset the effect

Code

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main2();

int WinMain()
{
    main2();
}
SDL_Texture* LoadTexture( const string& Filename, SDL_Renderer * renderer )
{
    if(renderer == nullptr)
        return nullptr;

    SDL_Texture* texture = IMG_LoadTexture( renderer, Filename.c_str() );
    if ( texture == nullptr )
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "(...): " << "Failed to load texture " << Filename << " error : " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }

    return texture;
}
int main2()
{
    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event event;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_JPG);

    SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2 Grayscale",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, 0);
    SDL_Renderer * renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    SDL_Texture * texture = LoadTexture("teeth.png", renderer);
    if(!texture)
        return 0;

    while (!quit)
    {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);

        switch (event.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            quit = true;
            break;
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
            {
            case SDLK_g:
                //Uint8 * r, *g, *b;


                SDL_SetTextureColorMod(texture, 100, 100, 100);
                //greytexture = Greyscale(image, renderer, GreyscalePercentage);
                break;
            case SDLK_1:
                SDL_SetTextureColorMod(texture, 1, 1, 1);
                break;
            }
            break;
        }

        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    //SDL_FreeSurface(image);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function SDL_SetTextureColorMod uses Uint8 for the Red, Green, and Blue color values. The value 0 would be no color. While the value 255 would be max color. So to reset the colors to normal, you would use 255 for Red, Green, and Blue. As in:

```
SDL_SetTextureColorMod(texture, 255, 255, 255);
```